# test.data.table() error message

Tags: r, data.table

Update: It got flagged as a duplicate to [[What does "The following object is masked from 'package:xxx' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137110/what-does-the-following-object-is-masked-from-packagexxx-mean]). The error message I refer to is "1 error out of 3729 (lastID=1380) in inst/tests/tests.Rraw". The previous link doesn't address that. (See comments section for followup).

---

I am wondering what this error in `test.data.table()` means:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16) -- "Full of Ingredients"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
......

> library(data.table)
data.table 1.9.4  For help type: ?data.table
*** NB: by=.EACHI is now explicit. See README to restore previous behaviour.
> test.data.table()
Running /mnt/sdb1/R-3.2.0/lib/R/library/data.table/tests/tests.Rraw 
Loading required package: reshape2
Loading required package: reshape

Attaching package: ?reshape?

The following objects are masked from ?package:reshape2?:

    colsplit, melt, recast

Loading required package: plyr

Attaching package: ?plyr?

The following objects are masked from ?package:reshape?:

    rename, round_any

Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: hexbin
Loading required package: nlme
Loading required package: xts
Loading required package: bit64
Loading required package: gdata
gdata: read.xls support for 'XLS' (Excel 97-2004) files ENABLED.

gdata: read.xls support for 'XLSX' (Excel 2007+) files ENABLED.

Attaching package: ?gdata?

The following object is masked from ?package:data.table?:

    last

The following object is masked from ?package:stats?:

    nobs

The following object is masked from ?package:utils?:

    object.size

Loading required package: GenomicRanges
Test 167.2 not run. If required call library(hexbin) first.
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type ITime. Defaulting to continuous
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type ITime. Defaulting to continuous
Test 841 not run. If required call library(xts) first.
Test 842 ran without errors but failed check that x equals y:
> x = last(list("a", 1:2, 89)) 
[[1]]
[1] 89

> y = 89 
[1] 89
Tests 897-899 not run. If required call library(bit64) first.


Running test id 1362.1     

Running test id 1362.2     

Running test id 1362.3     

Running test id 1362.4     

Running test id 1362.5     

Running test id 1362.6     

Running test id 1362.7     

Running test id 1362.8     

Running test id 1362.9     

Running test id 1362.11     

Running test id 1362.12     

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  1 error out of 3729 (lastID=1380) in inst/tests/tests.Rraw on Tue Jun 16 15:28:44 2015. Search tests.Rraw for test number 842.
```

Comment: the function `last()` gets masked by `gdata()`, where as we intend it to run data.table's. That test almost never runs on our tests, as we've xts installed.. Will fix, thanks. It's nothing to worry about, if that was your concern.

Comment: @Richie Cotton. I don't believe this is an exact duplicate. It's about an error message thrown by a unit test in data.table (1 error out of 3729 (lastID=1380)...) while the link you posted (to your own answer) explains the warning message "The following object is masked from ...". It does not directly address the error message. Could you please remove the duplicate mark (maybe change it into a link in the comment section)? Thank you. In any case, Arun answered the question perfectly.

Comment: fishtank, agreed. Richie must have overlooked it. i've reopened. This should be fixed now though..

Comment: @fishtank My apologies.  You might want to edit the question to make it clear which bit of the output from `test.data.table` is causing you the problem.