# test.data.table errors R

Tags: r, data.table

Ran a test for `data.table` on my new installation of R and got the below errors:

```
> test.data.table()
Error in eval(exprs[i], envir) : 
  10 errors out of 8403 (lastID=1887, endian==little, sizeof(long 
double)==16, sizeof(pointer)==8) in inst/tests/tests.Rraw on Tue Apr 03 
11:28:16 2018. Search tests.Rraw for test numbers: 546, 1693.4, 1693.5, 
1693.6, 1693.7, 1693.9, 1702.1, 1702.2, 1702.3, 1702.4.
```

All errors were of the kind:

```
Test testnum ran without errors but failed check that x equals y:
```

Where `testnum` is the test that failed (from above message).

Some more details:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rmarkdown_1.9     curl_3.1          caret_6.0-78      lattice_0.20-35   xts_0.10-1        zoo_1.8-1        
 [7] nlme_3.1-131.1    hexbin_1.27.2     testthat_2.0.0    plyr_1.8.4        knitr_1.20        bit64_0.9-7      
[13] bit_1.1-12        ggplot2_2.2.1     lubridate_1.7.2   data.table_1.10.5 gmad_0.0.0.9000   reshape2_1.4.3   
[19] reshape_0.8.7    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.3.1         ddalpha_1.3.1.1    tidyr_0.8.0        sfsmisc_1.1-2      splines_3.4.4     
 [6] foreach_1.4.4      prodlim_1.6.1      assertthat_0.2.0   highr_0.6          stats4_3.4.4      
[11] DRR_0.0.3          yaml_2.1.17        robustbase_0.92-8  ipred_0.9-6        pillar_1.2.1      
[16] backports_1.1.2    glue_1.2.0         digest_0.6.15      colorspace_1.3-2   recipes_0.1.2     
[21] htmltools_0.3.6    Matrix_1.2-12      psych_1.7.8        timeDate_3043.102  pkgconfig_2.0.1   
[26] CVST_0.2-1         broom_0.4.3        purrr_0.2.4        scales_0.5.0       gower_0.1.2       
[31] lava_1.6           tibble_1.4.2       withr_2.1.1        nnet_7.3-12        lazyeval_0.2.1    
[36] mnormt_1.5-5       survival_2.41-3    magrittr_1.5       evaluate_0.10.1    MASS_7.3-49       
[41] dimRed_0.1.0       foreign_0.8-69     class_7.3-14       tools_3.4.4        stringr_1.3.0     
[46] kernlab_0.9-25     munsell_0.4.3      bindrcpp_0.2       compiler_3.4.4     RcppRoll_0.2.2    
[51] rlang_0.2.0        grid_3.4.4         iterators_1.0.9    labeling_0.3       gtable_0.2.0      
[56] ModelMetrics_1.1.0 codetools_0.2-15   R6_2.2.2           dplyr_0.7.4        bindr_0.1         
[61] rprojroot_1.3-2    stringi_1.1.6      Rcpp_0.12.15       rpart_4.1-13       DEoptimR_1.0-8    
[66] tidyselect_0.2.4
```

Using RStudio as the IDE, version 1.1.442 `gmad` is a local package (does not have any conflicting function names, basically a package to access some private APIs).

Not sure if this is cause for concern - didn't encounter this on any previous installations. I've seen the answer for [test.data.table() error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879440/test-data-table-error-message) but it's for an older version and I am seeing multiple errors (vs one).

**EDIT**

Restarted RStudio, test run fines when no packages (other than base) are loaded (not even `data.table`).

Get errors after loading some packages.

I've copied the output for both cases. Too long to post in this question - here's a pastebin [link](https://pastebin.com/qJs6qh9L) and here's [another](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iBdMVunxefpi59hk8ufsYjap6qN6DlWh/view?usp=sharing) for GoogleDrive.

Regarding my local package `gmad`:

`NAMESPACE` imports:

```
import(data.table)
import(ggplot2)
import(httr)
importFrom(lubridate,round_date)
```

`DESCRIPTION` imports:

```
Imports:
  data.table,
  lubridate, 
  ggplot2,
    ggmap,
    httr
```

All other packages are installed from CRAN (versions noted in the session info above).

Comment: How did you install the package? Via CRAN or from github?

Comment: Downloaded the latest version from their Github page, instructions here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Comment: So you are using the development version ("v1.10.5 in development") which can still have problems - of course this does not explain the reason for the errors ;-) Any reason you are not installing from CRAN?

Comment: Had some issues with using `data.table::fread()` with the last version (esp. on MacOS) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637238/fread-ignores-sep-and-dec-when-reading-from-weblink

Comment: I have build the dev version from github on Ubuntu 14.04 and run the tests (`library(data.table); test.data.table()`) with **no** errors. I know you are using Windows (not Linux). So can you please post the complete code you use to run the tests (e. g. which libraries do you load first) + add the complete output of the `test.data.table` function call. Without reproducing the error msg and debugging `data.table` it's difficult to find the reason

Comment: Added the required info. The first test was performed after restarting RStudio and the second after loading four packages (`gmad`, `data.table`, `lubridate` and `ggplot2`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168145/discussion-between-r-yoda-and-gautam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.table` and `lubridate` use the same function names for some date/time-related functions so the order of loading both libraries decides which function from which package is called by the unit tests.

See this issue for details: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1135

I think to test the correct installation of data.table you shouldn't load lubridate at all.

If you want to use date/time functions in your code you have to choose which masking is better for you and load the libraries in the desired order...

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
test.data.table()  # runs without errors
```

If you reset the R session and load data.table first you will get some unit test errors

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
test.data.table()  # runs with unit test errors
```

saying e. g.

> Running test id 546 Test 546 ran without errors but failed check that
>   x equals y: